# OpenGL 3.3 Core-Profile: How to manage buffer arrays to draw several primitives?

Tags: opengl, buffer, draw

I'm following [this](https://learnopengl.com/) tutorial to write an OpenGL application. I have a dataset of 3D objects, where each object is described by:

- position (a 3D vector)
- bounding-box (lower and upper 3D vectors)
- point cloud (in my case, a [pcd](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcd_file_format.php) file)

So far, I managed to draw a point cloud loaded from a pcd file ([here](https://github.com/schizzz8/opengl_viewer) you can find the code). In the render loop I wrote:

```
  //3) bind VAO
  glBindVertexArray(_VAO);

  //4) draw
  glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS,0,_num_vertices);
```

where in the `GL_BUFFER_ARRAY` I stored the vertices of the cloud.

Now, my question is the following:

For this object I want also to draw a bounding-box (as a wireframe rectangle) and a set of 3d axis centered in its position (as a set of three cylinders). What is the best way to do that?

---

@MichaelIV

Thanks for your reply. I'm following your advice, but I get a weird behavior.

To populate the buffer I wrote the following code:

```
  Eigen::Vector3f min(1.7921,-0.2782,0.0);
  Eigen::Vector3f max(2.1521,0.1994,0.9915);

  insertVertex(_box_vertices,min.x(),min.y(),min.z(),0.0,0.0,1.0);
  insertVertex(_box_vertices,max.x(),min.y(),min.z(),0.0,0.0,1.0);
  insertVertex(_box_vertices,max.x(),max.y(),min.z(),0.0,0.0,1.0);
  insertVertex(_box_vertices,min.x(),max.y(),min.z(),0.0,0.0,1.0);

  _num_box_vertices = _box_vertices.size()/6.0f;
  std::cerr << "Box vertices:" << std::endl;
  for(size_t i=0; i<_num_box_vertices; ++i){
    std::cerr << _box_vertices[6*i] << " " << _box_vertices[6*i+1] << " " << _box_vertices[6*i+2] << " ";
    std::cerr << _box_vertices[6*i+3] << " " << _box_vertices[6*i+4] << " " << _box_vertices[6*i+5] << std::endl;
  }
```

where `_box_vertices` is a `std::vector<float>` array and `insertVertex` is just an utility function. If I print the array this is what I get:

```
dede@srrg-02:~/source/develop/opengl_viewer/bin$ ./opengl_viewer
Box vertices:
1.7921 -0.2782 0 0 0 1
2.1521 -0.2782 0 0 0 1
2.1521 0.1994 0 0 0 1
1.7921 0.1994 0 0 0 1
```

So, it should be correct. Then I use this code (OpenGL 3.3) to allocate gl objects:

```
  //[OPENGL] create box buffers
  glGenBuffers(1, &_bVBO);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _bVBO);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _box_vertices.size()*sizeof(float), &_box_vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

  glGenVertexArrays(1, &_bVAO);
  glBindVertexArray(_bVAO);

  //[OPENGL] link box vertex attributes
  glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
  glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3* sizeof(float)));
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

and this to render them:

```
  //3) bind box VAO
  glBindVertexArray(_bVAO);

  //4) draw box
  glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP,0,_num_box_vertices);
```

but the result is not what I would expect:

[image]

It looks like each line starts from (0,0,0) instead of starting from my desired point.

Can you please explain me how to fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: see [complete GL+GLSL+VAO/VBO C++ example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214) and look at the VAO/VBO example of cube. Your bbox will have almost the same points (use min,max values instead of `+/-1.0`) but different primitive (`GL_LINES`) and slightly different indices. However doing bbox in the old style api is easier (not posible in core profile) ...

Comment: You should put lines start/end positions into a buffer and do the same you do for other geometry but with GL_LINES, or LINE_STRIP mode.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I draw bounds (GL 4.5 API):

Init once:

```
         Gluint mVao = 0;
          //CReate VAO:
         glCreateVertexArrays(1, &mVao);

         glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(mVao, 0);
         glVertexArrayAttribFormat(mVao, 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);
         //Create VBO
         glCreateBuffers(1,&mVbo);
         glNamedBufferData(mVbo, dataSize, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
         //Bind VBO to VAO
         glVertexArrayAttribBinding(mVao, 0, 0);
         glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(mVao, 0, mVbo, 0, sizeof(float) * 3);
```

On every frame:

Prepare AABB vertices (using GLM math lib),aabb may come as some  `DrawDebug()` function argument:

```
        const GLfloat data[48] = {
        // Loop 1: XY Z (min)
        aabb.mMin.x, aabb.mMin.y, aabb.mMin.z,
        aabb.mMax.x, aabb.mMin.y, aabb.mMin.z,
        aabb.mMax.x, aabb.mMax.y, aabb.mMin.z,
        aabb.mMin.x, aabb.mMax.y, aabb.mMin.z,

        // Loop 2: XY Z (max)
        aabb.mMin.x, aabb.mMin.y, aabb.mMax.z,
        aabb.mMax.x, aabb.mMin.y, aabb.mMax.z,
        aabb.mMax.x, aabb.mMax.y, aabb.mMax.z,
        aabb.mMin.x, aabb.mMax.y, aabb.mMax.z,

        // Lists:
        // 1
        aabb.mMin.x, aabb.mMin.y, aabb.mMin.z,
        aabb.mMin.x, aabb.mMin.y, aabb.mMax.z,
        // 2
        aabb.mMax.x, aabb.mMin.y, aabb.mMin.z,
        aabb.mMax.x, aabb.mMin.y, aabb.mMax.z,
        // 3
        aabb.mMax.x, aabb.mMax.y, aabb.mMin.z,
        aabb.mMax.x, aabb.mMax.y, aabb.mMax.z,
        // 4
        aabb.mMin.x, aabb.mMax.y, aabb.mMin.z,
        aabb.mMin.x, aabb.mMax.y, aabb.mMax.z,
    };

    glNamedBufferSubData(mVbo,0, mDataSize, data);

   //combine line loop and line drawing to minimize number of draw calls:
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 4);
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 4, 4);
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 8, 8));
```

**IMPORTANT** note: I omitted here shader program binding as there is nothing special there.But you must provide shader program,where vertex shader performs transformation of the aabb coordinates with MVP (model-view-projection) matrix,or only with view - projection matrix if you transformed aabb vertices with model matrix on the client side.